# basic if statement, hide a button

Tags: actionscript-2

I would like to hide a button.

I'd like to pass a variable thru the url like so:

```
//test.swf?control=0;

control 1: being on, 0: off


if(_root.control =='1')
{
    button._visible = true;
}
```

Can anyone explain why the button is visible when `"test.swf?control=0;"` is passed thru the url.

Comment: presumably through comparing differing types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm taking  a stab in the dark here, but I think the button is visible by default.  You're probably never handling the other case; in other words, you're missing an 'else' block:

```
if(_root.control =='1')
{
    button._visible = true;
}
else
{
    button._visible = false;
}
```

which could also be written as

```
button._visible = (_root.control == '1')
```

In fact, the second format is generally preferred because it's a bit shorter with no expense of readability.

Comment: Thanks Mark. There's some smart fellas here on this site. Appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome -- accepting this answer just bumped me up to 10k, so thank *you* very much :)